# Android Studio 1.0 'runProguard' vs 'minifyEnabled'

Tags: android, android-studio, synchronization, proguard

During migration from Android Studio 0.9 to 1.0, I had to change the clause

```
buildTypes {
  release {
-     runProguard true
+     minifyEnabled true
}
```

as recommended [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0).

My app is running a standard Sync Adapter

```
public class SyncAdptr extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {
  private static Context mCtx;

  public SyncAdptr(Context ctx, boolean autoInit) { 
    super(ctx, autoInit); mCtx = ctx; 
  }

  static void syncStart(Account gooAcct, String authority) {
    ...
    ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(gooAcct, authority, true);
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

as a service:

```
public class SyncService extends Service {
  private static final Object sSyncAdapterLock = new Object();
  private static SyncAdptr sAndyScanSyncAdapter = null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    synchronized (sSyncAdapterLock) {
      if (sAndyScanSyncAdapter == null) {
        sAndyScanSyncAdapter = new SyncAdptr(getApplicationContext(), true);
      }
    }
  }
  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return sAndyScanSyncAdapter.getSyncAdapterBinder();
  }
}
```

It is a pretty standard boilerplate code that always worked.

By adding the 'minifyEnabled' clause as stated above, the synchronization stopped working with no error indication. I have tested it by removing the clause; the APK's size remained about the same as my debug version and sync was working. As soon as I plugged the 'minifyEnabled' in, the APK shrunk significantly (as expected) but the sync adapter quit again.

Any opinions? Suggestions?

**UPDATE (3 months later):**

I have progressed to '*Android Studio 1.1.0 AI-135.1740770 02/18/2015*', but still no difference. The 'minifyEnabled = true' has an effect that the service never starts. Anybody knows where to find 'ProgGuard configuration dump' as suggesed in the comments?

Comment: Any StackTrace or a ProgGuard configuration dump?

Comment: whats is your gradle version?

Comment: I see 'Android Studio 1.0.2, build 135.1653844, don't know what Gradle ver is in it.

Comment: in build.gradle you can see something like:
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }

Comment: yes, it is    "classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'"

Comment: got any error code for the service?

Comment: @NickJian Sorry I dropped the problem some time ago and did not get back to it (doing other things). So it kind-of hangs in the air, or it may be gone since there are at least 2 more Android Studio releases since. Will report when I get back to it.

Comment: Is Proguard removing or renaming a class or method required for your service? Look in the Proguard map output file.

Comment: Does the file have a name?

Comment: Have you tried adding -keep class <package-name>.SyncService { public <methods> } to your proguard-rules.pro file to stop proguard from removing it.  
Also I eventually found the proguard output files.  They are project-directory/proguard/
My build:grade has:
         release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

Comment: That project is on back burner now, I will try it and will report back, Thanks.